# Reheated half a cherry pie in the oven. Accidentally left it in said oven overnight

Tags: pie

Is it still safe to eat? It was cooked the other day, reheated last night, and left in the oven until 4:30, turned off of course.

Comment: Hello Alissa, you may want to read up on the basics of food safety in our tag wiki, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-safety.